# Apache Thrift server as client

Tags: c++, thrift

I've got server running in background and a program which should display data from server. I want to somehow launch method in my program from server. So server should be a sender, but how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why a server can't also be a client, just implement the interfaces from both sides and you're good.

The main thing to worry about is deadlocking: if you have a single threaded program which is waiting for the reply of the server, then it will not handle the request that the server sends, so the server is stuck and will not send a reply to the program.
This can be solved by starting the server implementations on different threads and letting them not block on the client thread.
Even better is to avoid having a server send back requests before sending replies, but cascading requests (forward requests to more specialized servers) should be no problem.